# Is it possible calling exe in web application

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an asp.net web application where i want to call (.exe i.e vb6 executable file ) when asp.net button is pressed(Client side). Is is possible? If possible plz share the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't run an EXE without some kind of prompt, you can use ClickOnce deployment to [deploy an unmanaged application](http://www.michaelckennedy.net/blog/2008/08/26/ClickOnceDeploymentForUnmanagedCodeCVB6Etc.aspx) and run it (and keep it updated). You would need to create a manifest that demands full trust and the user would have to grant that trust the first time they run the application.

Also note that this will only work in Internet Explorer or on other browsers that have a plugin to [enable ClickOnce deployment](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eeifaoomkminpbeebjdmdojbhmagnncl).

It's worth noting that Google actually deploys Google Chrome using ClickOnce to IE users.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, its not possible, at least not on client side.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, and there is no work-around.  This is **by-design** and cannot be changed, as a security measure to protect users from malicious web sites. I know your site isn't doing anything bad, but if you can run an exe, so can someone else with less-noble intentions. Again, there is no way to do this.

The closest you'll get is a flash or silverlight embed, or (on old internet explorer browsers) an activeX control.